# ConstraintLayout - Ellipsize start not working

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Using ellipsize **start** in a ConstraintLayout make the text truncated abruptly at the end.
I mention that i have constrained the view both at start and at end.

When i switch to ellipsize end, it works fine.

I also notice that in the Android Studio preview screen, the text is placed correctly, but at runtime, it is truncated at the end.

He's there an known issue about that ? Or am i doing something wrong ?

This is the code i use in XML:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:alpha="0.38"
        android:contentDescription="@string/location"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_location"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tint="@color/material_on_surface_disabled" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/area"
        style="?attr/textAppearanceCaption"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:singleLine="true"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/location"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
        tools:text="Long string, very long string that should be longer than the screen size, this is very long" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? To have [ ... ] at both start and end, right?

Comment: No, i only want to have [...] at start

Comment: Okay, please try the answer, @Ninjinski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering my own question here**

For anyone facing the same problem: i found what is going wrong here.

I found out that the problem isn't the ConstraintLayout, its the font style. Apparently, some font style cause `android:ellipsize="start"` (or even middle) to bug

You can simply use `android:layoutWidth="0dp"` with `android:singleLine="true"` on the `TextView` (I know its deprecated but it seems like maxLines could cause crash) and remove the font style, or found one that works.

Im curious to know why its happening, if someone has an idea

Answer (score 0):

**To have Ellipsize on end, try**

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
```

**To have Ellipsize on start, try**

```
android:ellipsize="start"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: I want ellipsize on start, and already have this setup, it doesn't work.

Comment: Please remove the line  `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" ' and give a try

Comment: At my end, it renders fine. Adjust android:layout_width to some constant size 100dp or so and check. As per Google doc, [  you should use the above layout_constrainedWidth/Height attribute along with width=wrap_content.]

Comment: Im not using constrainedWidth anymore, when i set the text view at a fixed size (other than 0dp), the view is centered which is normal, but i face the same problem